# Not able to parse a file using Java Spark API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file with entries like this

```
10.28 INFO  [EFKLogger] - POGUpdateTenestenerServiceImpl: Entering listener with object 624866045533
```

Now using Spark i want to count the number of queues getting hit every hour . Queue is `POGUpdateTenestenerServiceImpl` . Now i want a JAVARDD that only contains the time and the queue so i can perform operation on it . I am new top spark and only found ways to either create RDD with all words or as a whole line . I only want two words from a line . HOw can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `textFile` function of the SparkContext to read the file:

Here is a Scala example, it can be translated easily to java

```
val text = sc.textFile("data.csv") //Read the file
val words = text.map(line=> line.split(" ")) //Break the line to words
```

Now words is an array of words, you can take the first second and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Thanks i did it anyway using the map function . Your solution works as well